# Cannot debug project in VS 2012 after upgrade to Win 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a C# project which was working on Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 7.

I've now updated my operating system to Windows 10 but I am encountering issues and can't debug my project anymore.

How can I fix the below errors?

`Error  3   Task host node exited prematurely. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.`

`Error  4   The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match target type.`

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but I would upgrade your VS to 2019 ASAP - there's no reason why you would want to stay on VS 2012.

Comment: a suggestion, try to run the visual studio as administrator - and see if works